# I couldn't find the differences between these two

Tags: python-3.x

Giving error:

```
temp = int(input("What is the temperature outside?"))
if temp >= 0 and <= 30:
    print("the temperature is good today!")
```

The original code which is not giving error:

```
temp = int(input("What is the temperature outside?: "))

if temp >= 0 and temp <= 30:
    print("the temperature is good today!")
```

Can someone explain me the differences cuz i couldnt find any. i will appreciate it :)

Comment: Compare the lines character per character. You will find two differences, one of which being the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp` variable is missing in the first conditional

[image: difference]